# How to return a JSON from webAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I've got the class:

```
public class AObject {
    public string RawJson { get; set; }
    public decimal Rating { get; set; }
    public BObject BObject { get; set; }
}

public class BObject {
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

The question is - how to return a AObject as a valid JSON object.
AObject.RawJson is a string which contains a serialized to string JSON-object (from remote API).

If I use the default ways of serialization, web-api returns AObject.RawJson as a string but not as a json-object.

Comment: Show the entire relevant code. BTW, do you only want to return (send) the `RawJson` string?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to first deserialize the `RawJson` into an intermediate object using, e.g. [Newtonsoft deserializer](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm):

```
public class AObject {
    // --->      <--- Changed 
    public object RawJson { get; set; }
    // --->^^^^^^<---
    public decimal Rating { get; set; }
    public BObject BObject { get; set; }
}

public class BObject {
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

...

AObject test = new AObject();
test.RawJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(remoteJsonResult);
```

If you then hook up a debugger you should see the remote JSON having been converted into an object which will then get correctly *re*-serialized back to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
AObject a = new AObject();
string json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(a);
return json;
```

Comment: Please include a description of the code in your answer.